# Eternal Bear market: Causes and consequences

Tags: society, economy

Investing in the stock market is a sane thing to do, as the general trend is upward. If your investing horizon is further enough (~10 years) you're all but certain to get a positive Return On Investment.

Sometimes, the trend reverses and it switches from a Bull to a Bear market, but it's just a temporary situation. As stated, the general, underlying **trend is upward**. But...

### **What if the trend reversed permanently?**

How could that situation be reached, if at all? Which would be the likely consequences of this?

Comment: Is it *just* the stock market that is acting as a bear market, or is the entire economy reacting in the same way?

Comment: That would be the end of the world as we know it. End of pensions, end of social welfare. Excepting World War III, the only thing which comes to mind is a serious global permament negative population growth. A long-term decrease in the price of shares would tend to amplify itself quickly leading to a world-wide economic crash.

Comment: @CortAmmon The stock market is acting that way as a consequence of external factors. It's not like someone hacked into them and is displaying bogus information. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: @AlexP I kept picturing Mad Max, but I need as much input as I can get.

Comment: Could you explain *how it is unclear* what I'm asking for? I'm not sure how to make it more evident.

Answer (score 8):

This sort of situation is bad news.  The stock market is not a magic machine which multiplies your money over time.  The stock market is a tool for trading investments.  **The value of the stock market is entirely based on people's valuing of those investments.**  Thus, for the stock market to go down continuously, people must continuously be valuing those investments less and less.

This process cannot go on indefinitely under normal conditions.  A stock has *some* intrinsic value as a share of the equipment owned by the company.  If a stock goes down too low, vultures come in, buy up the stock, and then use that controlling interest in the company to force them to liquidate assets, passing that value back to shareholders (us).  Typically the perceived value of a company (which includes its growth potential) is much higher than their raw assets, so this doesn't happen often.  Every now and then, a company can make a mistake which suddenly evaporates all of their value.  It's usually messy.

To have all companies doing this, continuously, implies that something has gone *very very* wrong.  For some reason, this natural process is not occurring.  There may be some government nationalization going on, sucking up all of the value.  Or perhaps high velocity trading has destabilized the market so greatly that nobody can afford to trade anymore.

An alternative would be for the value of stocks to asymptotically approach the value of their liquid assets.  This would prevent them from dropping below the value of their liquid assets, so the vultures would not come in.  However, very quickly we would see that the return on investment is exactly 0%.  You might as well be holding onto cash at that point.

Maybe.

If you were living during a period of hyper-inflation, a return on an investment of 0% actually looks quite good.  Hyper-inflation, of course, cannot last forever.  It always explodes as the cost of ink to print more currency raises above the value of the printed result.  We've also seen bonds go below 0% during some economic crises.  In the great recession, German bonds were actually paying negative interest rates.  Basically, you would pay them for the privilege of not being able to use your money!  But it did make sense, as the rest of Europe was quite uncertain.  The entire Euro currency was being questioned.  The theory was that Germany, if they did leave the Euro behind, would more than likely convert their national debt to their new currency rather than default.  This made Germany a safe haven for avoiding risk.

Historically, this is actually how banks worked.  They would hold onto your valuables, for a fee.

Comment: There are also countries with [negative interest rates](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-32284393) which make 0% look better than cash.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason for a perpetual bear market I can think of, is that for some reason people prefer to invest directly, rather than through the market. As in small firms rather than limited companies.

The reason people invest in limited companies is to limit liability. I invest \$100, at worst I'll lose $100, no more. Firms have no such protection. Normally, therefore, it is much more risky to invest in firms when you can invest in a company.

This scenario can thus only occur if people lose faith in the system that makes this possible. Or rather, develop faith that, "if I invest \$100, I'll lose $100; much better odds to gamble with everything instead."

This situation implies that:

1. There are regular bubbles in the market, which the regulator ignores;
2. The people forming companies are usually (not merely often) predatory towards small investors;
3. The entry barriers to forming a company are high, at least if you're not in the right circles.

In other words, there is an oligarchy in place at the top, and people can't trust the system (I think I already said that).

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong theory that capitalism works as long as growth is possible, and global growth is possible only so long as the pie gets larger. Prior to the Industrial Revolution, wealth was often seen as evil. Why? Because the trade pie of the planet, each nation, even each town, was relatively stable. To become rich was always at the expense of someone else. With industrialization and exploration, the global pie itself got larger. Folks who look at the macro economy over hundreds of years have expressed concern that between the lack of Earthly exploration and climate change necessitating less action, we might be on the verge of a leveling off of growth, and no growth is the same as contraction as far as capitalism is concerned... no one can make a true profit, which either reduces the urge to trade or leads to higher trade barriers. And that is a permanent bear market. (So if you're a capitalist, consider supporting space and ocean colonization!)

Check out the book: "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind" (available on Amazon) for one non-fiction book on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

A stock is also known as a share because that is precisely what it is. You own a share of a company's assets and of the money it pays our in dividends.

I can't see how there can be a permanently falling real value of all stocks. Obviously if extreme communists or fascists gain power, it's possible that all companies are nationalised or siezed and if this were global, then "stock market" would be history until capitalism was re-invented some generations later.. But that is a crash to zero, not a permanent downtrend. Crash to zero of an individual company is of course commonplace. It's called bankruptcy.

As long as the legal framework of company law is maintained, there will be a low point for the stock of any company that is solvent and trading, when the stock is clearly a bargain. If people think that a future crash to zero is likely, that point may seem in retrospect to have been insanely cheap. This has actually happened, though insane "bubble" over-valuation seems to be more common.

"In the short term the stockmarket is a voting machine. In the long term it is a weighing machine".